# Not able to use drag and drop

Tags: drag-and-drop

I am not able to drag and drop a docx file from desktop to Trash. And there is no application running in background. What couls be reason for this?

Comment: Which Ubuntu version? What do you mean by "from Desktop" ? and "to Trash" ? You should know that the Desktop in 20.04 can be considered broken (imo a bug), many features are missing. Use the file manager for operations like this and don't care about the desktop.

Comment: I am using ubuntu 20.04 LTS version. Actually I wanted to delete a docx file which is located on my desktop by using drag and drop method. But I was unable to do so.@pLumo

Comment: use DEL key instead

Comment: I don't know why but DEL key is also not working now. But this drag and drop method was working some time earlier.

Comment: I think you need to make this post a bit clearer.